# A bash command to sum up the numbers in a Kubernetes table?

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

After using k top pods -A in Kubernetes to get CPU usage and memory, is there any way to sum up those columns with a bash command? Or is it not possible for them to be converted to numbers because of the units? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J48I.png)
I'd like to be able to get the sum of both of these columns, is there a bash command that could do this? I can't seem to figure out how to use awk to do it.
I tried awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}', I couldn't really figure it out. The terminal just stopped taking input after that and didn't output anything. Would appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: Please don't use screen grab images for simple text. Just copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Kubernetes but some Googling shows that the output really looks like this (which is not what your screen grab showed):

```
NAMESPACE            NAME                                                        CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
kube-system          coredns-558bd4d5db-k7mfl                                    8m           11Mi            
kube-system          coredns-558bd4d5db-qwrrk                                    8m           12Mi
```

From the limited research I did it is not clear if the units are always `m` (milliunits) and `Mi` (megabyte?). If those are the only unit suffixes then simply ignore them. Since converting a string to a number in Awk ignores any characters after the last digit you don't have to do anything.

```
BEGIN {
    cpu = 0
    mem = 0
}
NR == 1 { next }
{
    cpu += $3
    mem += $4
}
END {
    print cpu, mem
}
```

For the example data above this will print `16 23`. If the unit suffix can be other strings you will need to test which suffix is present and apply an appropriate scaling factor to the number.

Comment: you don't have to initialize the variables, they are already 0 and you can use `NR!=1` to avoid the `next`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, Yes, I know that. I've been programming since 1976 and am a Senior Software Engineer. I was being explicit because the O.P. is clearly extremely inexperienced and I felt being explicit was warranted.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, I'll also point out that I have never liked the implicit initialization of variables in Awk that depends on the context. It is useful for quick and dirty CLI invocations but should be avoided in Awk code meant to be run more than once. Explicit is usually better than implicit from a long term maintenance view point.

Comment: opinions, opinions,...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, could you maybe direct me to the links you used? I tried the command and got the error "BEGIN: command not found", maybe I could use the page you looked at to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a little experience in bash but not any in Kubernetes, googling how to sum columns in bash of Kubernetes tables wasn't getting me any links, maybe I could try reading the page you used. I'm unfamiliar with awk as well.

Comment: My program was written in the AWK language. If you put the program in a file named `prog.awk` you would run it with `awk -f prog.awk`. Try `man awk` to read the documentation.

Comment: I see, I created prog.awk in vim and tried running it but nothing happened, it just keeps running and doesn't give any output. I had to kill the process, it wasn't returning anything. I don't know if the loop is maybe infinite for some reason?

Comment: You didn't give it any data. Try copy/pasting the three lines at the top of my answer into a file named `data` then run `awk -f prog.awk data`.

Comment: Also, just running `awk -f prog.awk` without a data filename will cause awk to read from stdin; i.e., your terminal.

Comment: Success! Thank you so much for your help. I hope I get better at bash

Comment: @AnnFlus, Please accept my answer by clicking on the up-arrow to mark it useful.

Comment: Sure, have done it. I was curious though is there any way to achieve this without having to paste the output into a file called data, and be able to sum it directly in the command line using prog.awk?

Comment: @AnnFlus, Just pipe the output of the command that fetches the data into the `awk` command; e.g., `kubectl top pods -A | awk -f prog.awk`.